# XSLT getting last element

Tags: xslt, xpath, menu

I am trying to find the last element in my xml, which looks like:

```
<list>
  <element name="A" />
  <element name="B" >
    <element name="C" />
    <element name="D" >
      <element name="D" />
      <element name="E" />
      <element name="F" />
      <element name="G" />
    </element>
    <element name="H" />
    <element name="I" />
  </element>
</list>
```

I need to get some kind of reverse menu, where current element and parents are highlighted as "active" and sibling as "inactive". Instead in result I have a messy tree only when  I suppose "D" element clicked.

Double D elements are my problem. When I use
`select="//element[@name='D'][last()]"` or `select="//element[@name='D' and last()]"` (btw which one is correct?) first time *first occurrence of* D element is selected (debugger shows that). Here is xsl

```
<xsl:template match="list">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//navelement[@name = 'D'][last()]" mode="active"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element">
    <ul class="menu">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::node()" mode="inactive"/>
        <li><a>....</a></li>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()" mode="inactive"/>
    </ul>   
    <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::element" mode="active"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element" mode="inactive">
        <li><a>....</a></li>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 390, accepted):

You need to put the `last()` indexing on the nodelist result, rather than as part of the selection criteria. Try:

```
(//element[@name='D'])[last()]
```

Comment: TIL: Apparently there is no [first()] but you can use [1]

Comment: It's funny that I still get votes for this question after 7 years. It really shows how flawed and defective XSLT is. Avoid XSLT as a plague :D

Comment: @Nik . It rather shows how few people understand the strength of the language.

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed I was about to say XSLT was already dead 15 years ago but occasionally got some hype when everyone was writing PHP code... Then I opened your profile and see you call yourself a PHP expert :D

Comment: @Nik, somehow a got a smile on my fase but I don't understand why. Do you mean PHP is dead also? Or do mean that PHP is flawed and defective as well? 
That said, being an expert in a software-language can be quite doubtfull. Allthough when it is dead for 15 years it must be possible.  ;-)

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed I mean I expected my message saying that XSLT was popular in PHP-community only to be quite subjective/playful. But then the person I was replying to turned out to be a member of the PHP community :) So my initial message got a real-world proof :)

Comment: @Nik: I'm a real-world-proof example. I like it. :). As I like XSLT, no better language if you have to handle XML.

Comment: Here, get a vote after 14 years :D