# How to get last position in XSLT

Tags: xslt

How can I get last position

```
<contrib contrib-type="author" corresp="no">
  <surname>Duan</surname>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author" corresp="no">
  <surname>Ding</surname>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author" corresp="no">
  <surname>Li</surname>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author" corresp="no">
  <surname>Miao</surname>
</contrib>
```

This is the XSL

```
<xsl:template match="contrib">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I need this Output: Duan, Ding, Li and Miao

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459132/xslt-getting-last-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using the **last()** function, but possibly thinking it is not working. Although you have not shown the full XSLT, it is possible you are relying on XSLT's built-in templates to select the **contrib** elements. In this case, it is selecting nodes in the XML, not just elements, and the **position()** relates to the nodes just selected, including text nodes. The last **contrib** element is not the last node because there is a white-space node after the last element.

What you could do is use the **strip-space** command to remove such white-space nodes.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="contrib">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
          <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="position() > 1">
          <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this may not work if there are other elements in the XML. So, to get around this, you could explicitly select the **contrib** elements, in which case **position** would pick up the last one. Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="contrib" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="contrib">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
          <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="position() > 1">
          <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in a proper context (add a root template) the function `position()` doesn't work without it.

Check it out:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/"> 
<contribs>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</contribs>
</xsl:template>

<!-- your template -->

<xsl:template match="contrib">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You must also wrap convenient-ly your xml data (multiroot xml is not correct)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<doc>

<contrib contrib-type="author" corresp="no">
  <surname>Duan</surname>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author" corresp="no">
  <surname>Ding</surname>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author" corresp="no">
  <surname>Li</surname>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author" corresp="no">
  <surname>Miao</surname>
</contrib>

</doc>
```

For a nicer result you have to shift the "and" text part after

```
position()=last()-1
```

and leave text after position()=last() empty, but this can be easily deduced and executed, isn't it ?

This looks as a poorly prepared homework exercise!!

Comment: @michael.hor257k of course I did! (with haskell hxt xslt, and also saxon.jar):

java -jar /usr/share/java/saxon.jar contrib.xml contrib2.xsl


-- result: <contribs>Duan, Ding, Li, Miao and </contribs>

Comment: The "and" needs to come BEFORE "Miao", INSTEAD OF the comma.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I know that the program can be better, but position() was not working without a root template that was not there