# Targeting all but last iteration/node doesn't work

Tags: xslt

I would like to target all but the last iterations/nodes to give them a bottom border. Only the last iteration should not have a bottom border.

This is my XSLT now:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:decimal-format name="european" decimal-separator=',' grouping-separator='.'/>
  <xsl:template match="items">
  {$fallback = 0}
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
      <table align="center" cellpadding="0" class="resize" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:600px; background-color:#ffffff">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">
           <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:190px" class="resize" align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff">
           {$fallback = 1}
             <tr>
               <td align="center" class="no_padding" style="padding:20px;">Do some code here
               </td>
             </tr>
           </table>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now I tried doing something like `<xsl:if test="position() = last()"><td align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;"></xsl:if><xsl:if test="position() != last()"><td align="center"></xsl:if>`

However I see nothing happening in my output HTML. Also if I just add `<xsl:if test="position() = last()">asdjasdkkasdjasd</xsl:if>` I do not see any text in the output.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example input and the expected output - see: [mcve].

Comment: smells like: [How to get last position in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603626/how-to-get-last-position-in-xslt)

Comment: What is the {$fallback=1} ?

Answer (score -1):

Use this to detect your last iteration:

```
<xsl:when test="position()=last()">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <xsl:text> last iteration </xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
```

EDIT: some explanation on this.

When having an XML like:

```
<items>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
</items>
```

I can use a tool like `xmlstarlet` to select the last `item`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m //item -v . -i "position()=last()" -o "X" -b -n xml2.xml
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4X
```

The XSLT can be generated for this command (see help of xmlstartlet ) and looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//item">
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
          <xsl:text>X</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="value-of-template">
    <xsl:param name="select"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$select"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($select)[position()&gt;1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This shows the XSLT code which is responsible for adding a `X` to the last item.

I also checked that changing the condition to `position()!=last()`, then the `X` appears at line 1,2 and 3.

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce OP's problem?