# last() is not applied

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test, below is my DOM:

```
<body>    
<div class='t'><span>1</span></div> 
<div class='t'></div> 
<div class='t'><span>2</span></div> 
<div class='t'><span>3</span></div> 
<div class='t'><span>4</span></div> 
<div class='t'><span>5</span></div> 
<div class='t'><span>6</span></div> 
<div class='t'><span>7</span></div> 
<div class='tt'></div> 
</body>
```

when I use: `//div[@class='t'][last()]` I get:

```
<div class="t"><span>7</span></div>
```

but when I use: `//div[@class='t' and last()]`  I get:

```
<div class="t"><span>1</span></div>
<div class="t"/>
<div class="t"><span>2</span></div>
<div class="t"><span>3</span></div>
<div class="t"><span>4</span></div>
<div class="t"><span>5</span></div>
<div class="t"><span>6</span></div>
<div class="t"><span>7</span></div>
```

it's like `last()` is not applied to the second xpath, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`//div[@class='t'][last()]` ... means pick the element from the list of matches (where `@class='t'`) whose index is last, which is what you want.

With `//div[@class='t' and last()]`, the already-calculated value of `last()` is applied for each match in the list purely on the basis of being != 0, and it will cause the `div` matcher to return FALSE only if `last()` is zero. In other words, the `last()` does **not** get used to select a single node from the list. That's definitely not what you want.

**For example:** if `last()` evaluates to 5, `//div[@class='t' and 5]` will return every matching element in the list because 5 != 0.

The net result is that if *any* nodes are matched (`last()` > 0), *all* of them will be returned.

**See also:** [XSLT getting last element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1459132/954442)

Comment: is there any documentation where I can get this information? generally about all Xpath functions